# Chrome launched with Selenium WebDriver does not list speechSynthesis.voices

Tags: java, google-chrome, selenium, text-to-speech

I want to launch Chrome using the WebDriver

```
System.setProperty("webdriver.chrome.driver", DrivePath +"chromedriver.exe");
ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions(); 
options.addArguments("--lang=nl_NL");
WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get(<LOCAL HTML>);
driver.close();
```

The page uses speechSynthesis .

To troubleshoot I have a javascript function that lists the available voices:

```
for (var i = 0; i < window.speechSynthesis.getVoices().length; i++ ) {

    var voice = window.1 element
    .getVoices()[i];
    var name = voice.name + " (" + voice.lang + ")";
    var div = document.getElementById('voices');
    div.innerHTML = div.innerHTML + name+' ';
}
```

When I open the page with Chrome (Chrome.exe) I get the expected result:

> native () Google Deutsch (de-DE) Google US English (en-US) Google UK
>   English Female (en-GB) Google UK English Male (en-GB) Google español
>   (es-ES) Google español de Estados Unidos (es-US) Google français
>   (fr-FR) Google हिन्दी (hi-IN) Google Bahasa Indonesia (id-ID) Google
>   italiano (it-IT) Google 日本語 (ja-JP) Google 한국의 (ko-KR) Google
>   Nederlands (nl-NL) Google polski (pl-PL) Google português do Brasil
>   (pt-BR) Google русский (ru-RU) Google 普通话（中国大陆） (zh-CN) Google 粤語（香港）
>   (zh-HK) Google 國語（臺灣） (zh-TW)

When the same page is opened using the java (selenium) code I only get:

> native ()

What options do I need to set to get the other voices ?
I have read somewhere that maybe I need to point to an extension (*.crx). If this is the case, please share the crx file :-)